# How to change nav,footer,cart color in prestashop?

Tags: themes, prestashop

so i have a little problem, i read about that color can be changed by changing lines in global.css, so i've found that file inside themes directory and change it in colors that i want, so i uploaded it again online but nothing happens. ive tried several methods using cpanel,FTP client, even exported and uploaded new copy of that theme with changed colors, but nothing happens, i dont know what else to do. Everything else is nice, and how i want it but not this one, i just want to change 3 colors that's the point, i dont want that grey color i want orange. and im freaking out dunno what to do. and yea btw i dont want to change colors by changing color scheme. thanks guys for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

in backoffice `Advanced preferences -> Performance -> Clear cache` button in top right corner